# Notification Android : Don't show notification when app is open?

Tags: java, android, android-intentservice

I'm working on a project and I use Intent Service with wakefulBroadcastReceiver to schedule alarm and send notification. There are no problems this far. But I want when I open my app, it don't displaying notification again. Please any idea for this problem?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your notification receiver when you receive the notification you can check whether the app is in background or not and take a decision of showing the notification accordingly.

Here's a code to check whether the app is in background or not.

```
public class MyGcmPushReceiver extends GcmListenerService {

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     * @param from   SenderID of the sender.
     * @param bundle Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *               For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle bundle) {
        // Check here whether the app is in background or running.
        if(isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // Show the notification
        } else {
            // Don't show notification
        }
    }

        /**
        * Method checks if the app is in background or not
        */
        private boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
            boolean isInBackground = true;

            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
                for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                    if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                        for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                            if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                                isInBackground = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                    isInBackground = false;
                }
            }
            return isInBackground;
        }
}
```

Comment: I call Method Above inside onCreate activity?? @Mr. Rabbit

Comment: yes call is from activity but post this in application class

Comment: @FinnD You need to call this method inside your receiver, not in onCreate. I've edited the answer which shows example for GCM receiver in case if you are using the same.