# Firebase chat prevent push notification when user is already chatting

Tags: firebase, push-notification

I'm building a chat application using Firebase as database and FCM as push notification service.

While building the app, I realized that I shouldn't always fire a push notification for every message created. For example, a user may already be chatting, and should not receive push notifications for that conversation.

One way to implement this is by letting the server know every time a user enters a conversation and conditionally send push notifications off of that. However, this is a server-side solution, and I'd like to know if there is any existing client-side solution using Firebase.

Comment: Since the server side is the part of the system sending the messages, it seems to me that the solution is going to have to be primarily on that side.  The client just receives messages.

Comment: @DougStevenson I see, I just found it weird that the server should know users' current screen. But I guess this is the best way to approach this problem. Thanks!

Comment: The server can keep sending messages, and the client can just ignore them.  If you're using FCM, the messages cost nothing to send, and you may only pay minimal costs for the backend processing.

Comment: @DougStevenson Oh is there a way to make the client ignore messages despite them containing 'notification' payload? AFAIK an FCM message containing 'notification' payload triggers the push notification regardless of whether the app is in foreground or background.

Comment: By "ignore", I mean your code chooses to do nothing with the message upon receipt.  You can't change the default triggering behavior for messages.

Answer (score 0):

We can check whether the app is in the background or not with a boolean method. Using the activity manager, we can check if the application ( with your package name) is running or not! then using simple if-else on "onMessageReceived" you can opt to display notification else none.
Use this in Firebase Messaging Service Class you created:

```
public class MyGcmPushReceiver extends GcmListenerService {

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     * @param from   SenderID of the sender.
     * @param bundle Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *               For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle bundle) {
        // Check here whether the app is in background or running.
        if(isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // Show the notification
        } else {
            // Don't show notification
        }
    }

        /**
        * Method checks if the app is in background or not
        */
        private boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
            boolean isInBackground = true;

            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
                for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                    if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                        for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                            if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                                isInBackground = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                    isInBackground = false;
                }
            }
            return isInBackground;
        }
}
```

Original credit goes to Mr. Rabbit https://stackoverflow.com/a/42312210/10742321

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.