# Chat App - How to stop push notifications when Chat Activity is in foreground?

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

newbie here.

I have developed a chat app using firebase database and android studio and used firebase functions as well as firebase messaging service to send notifications to users when they receive a  new message. 
Everything is working fine. My only problem is that I want to stop notifications service when the two users are already chatting (have the ChatActivity already running).

I have looked everywhere but cannot find a solution
Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived( RemoteMessage remoteMessage ) {


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){




                super.onMessageReceived ( remoteMessage );


                String notification_title = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "title" );
                String notification_message = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "body" );


                String click_action = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "click_action" );
                String visit_user_id = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "from_user_id" );
                String visit_user_name = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "userName" );

                Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse ("android.resource://"+getApplicationContext ().getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.dog  );

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent ( click_action );
                resultIntent.putExtra ( "visit_user_id", visit_user_id );
                resultIntent.putExtra ( "userName", visit_user_name );

                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity (
                                this,
                                0,
                                resultIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );


                OreoNotification oreoNotification = new OreoNotification ( this );

                Notification.Builder builder = oreoNotification.getOreoNotification ( notification_title, notification_message,resultPendingIntent ).setSmallIcon ( R.drawable.finalpawslogofour )
                        .setVibrate ( new long[]{500, 500} ).setAutoCancel ( true ).setSound ( alarmSound );


                int mNotificationId = ( int ) System.currentTimeMillis ();



                oreoNotification.getManager().notify ( mNotificationId, builder.build ());


        }else{


                super.onMessageReceived ( remoteMessage );


                String notification_title = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "title" );
                String notification_message = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "body" );


                String click_action = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "click_action" );
                String visit_user_id = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "from_user_id" );
                String visit_user_name = remoteMessage.getData ().get ( "userName" );

                Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse ("android.resource://"+getApplicationContext ().getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.dog  );


                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder ( this ).setSmallIcon ( R.drawable.finalpawslogofour ).setContentTitle ( notification_title ).setContentText ( notification_message )
                        .setVibrate ( new long[]{500, 500} ).setAutoCancel ( true ).setSound ( alarmSound );



                Intent resultIntent = new Intent ( click_action );
                resultIntent.putExtra ( "visit_user_id", visit_user_id );
                resultIntent.putExtra ( "userName", visit_user_name );


                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity (
                                this,
                                0,
                                resultIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );

                mBuilder.setContentIntent ( resultPendingIntent );


                int mNotificationId = ( int ) System.currentTimeMillis ();

                NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = ( NotificationManager ) getSystemService ( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );

                mNotifyMgr.notify ( mNotificationId, mBuilder.build ());






        }






}
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Mr. Rabbit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312167/notification-android-dont-show-notification-when-app-is-open) you could implement the isAppIsBackgrounded() method in your class which extends FirebaseMessagingService:

```
private boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
            boolean isInBackground = true;

            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
                for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                    if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                        for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                            if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                                isInBackground = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                    isInBackground = false;
                }
            }
            return isInBackground;
        }
```

Another, yet crude, method would be to use  `SharedPreferences` to know if a ChatActivity is active or not.